# Select column names whose entries are not null

Tags: mysql, select, null

I would like to have a list of those columns of a table that have at least one non-`NULL` data entries in them.

In other words, I would like to get the column names for which the following returns at least one entry:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table WHERE column_name IS NOT NULL
```

I tried the following:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = "table_name"
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name IS NOT NULL
)
```

But this also returns the column names where all the entries are `NULL`.

So how do I get only those columns with non-`NULL` entries?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create from the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/columns-table.html) table a string that contains the SQL you wish to execute, then [prepare a statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) from that string and execute it.

The SQL we wish to build will look like:

```
  SELECT 'column_a'
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE `column_a` IS NOT NULL
  HAVING COUNT(*)
UNION ALL
  SELECT 'column_b'
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE `column_b` IS NOT NULL
  HAVING COUNT(*)
-- etc.
```

(One could omit the `WHERE` clause and substitute `COUNT(*)` for `COUNT(column)`, but I *think* that might be less efficient on indexed columns).

This can be done using the following:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 4294967295;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
 ' SELECT ',QUOTE(COLUMN_NAME),
 ' FROM   table_name',
 ' WHERE `',REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '`', '``'),'` IS NOT NULL',
 ' HAVING COUNT(*)'
SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
INTO   @sql
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name';

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32193/28/3).

Comment: Sorry... Viewing on iPad and thought it registered... Definitely worth the up vote :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this procedure this will print columns names of a table which have atleast one not null rows.

```
create or replace procedure list_col_notNull(tblName in varchar2)
as
lv_col_name varchar2(200);
lv_ctr number;
lv_sql varchar2(400);
CURSOR cur_col_name is
SELECT column_name
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS U
WHERE table_name = tblName order by column_name asc;
begin
open cur_col_name;

LOOP
    FETCH cur_col_name INTO lv_col_name; 
    EXIT WHEN cur_col_name%NOTFOUND; 
    lv_sql := 'select count(1) From ' || tblName || ' where ' || lv_col_name || ' is not null'  ;  
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_sql into lv_ctr;
    if lv_ctr > 0
    then
        dbms_output.put_line(lv_col_name);
    end if;
```