# Get columns ia a table when it's defined how not null

Tags: mysql, select

I have a big table and I need get the name of the columns that is not null. For example, in this table:

```
id: long not null,
name: varchar(100) not null,
short_name: varchar(20) default null.
```

with an SQL SELECT, I would like that it will returned only the name of this columns:

```
id
name
```

Can I do this?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400071/select-column-names-whose-entries-are-not-null

Comment: Yes, you can do this.

Comment: Check for `IS_NULLABLE` column in `information_schema`

Comment: Sorry, I try to search but I don't find it before. I needed to try more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for `IS_NULLABLE` column in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

**Query**

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name'
AND IS_NULLABLE = 'NO';
```